# Como faço a filtragem de dados por data em um dataframe(Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Sendo que teria que criar um dataframe novo com as informações vindas dessas datas abaixo.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
%matplotlib inline
races = pd.read_csv('races.csv')
results = pd.read_csv('results.csv')
last10M = pd.merge(results, races, how='outer', on='raceId')
start = datetime.datetime(int(2008), int(4), 20)
end = datetime.datetime(int(2008), int(4), 20)
```

Estou empacado nessa ultima parte, as datas eu ja fiz só que falta fazer a filtragem pelo dataframe 'last10M'. O dataframe 'last10M' teria que ser filtrado no campo 'data' de 2008 a 2018

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo (poucas linhas) do teu results.csv e races.csv pff, para adequar a resposta o mais possível ao teu caso

Comment: Ambos estão aqui https://www.kaggle.com/cjgdev/formula-1-race-data-19502017/data

Comment: Eu teria que no dataframe 'last10M' na coluna 'date' filtrada de 2008 a 2018

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta o seguinte:

```
races = pd.read_csv('races.csv', parse_dates=['date']) # tratar a coluna date como datetime
results = pd.read_csv('results.csv')
last10M = pd.merge(results, races, how='outer', on='raceId')
interval = (last10M['date'] > '2008-01-01') & (last10M['date'] <= '2018-01-01')
df_interval = last10M.loc[interval]
```

Comment: 'df' is not defined

Comment: Basicamente esqueci do parse_dates para criar a expressão. Obrigado !